# How to validate file upload? [Play Framework]

Tags: file-upload, playframework, playframework-2.0, javabeans

I have a simple bean, like that:

```java
package models;

import play.data.validation.Constraints;

public class Upload
{
    @Constraints.Required
    @Constraints.MinLength(4)
    @Constraints.MaxLength(40)
    public String name;

    @Constraints.Required
    public String inputFile;
}
```

and form, like that:

```java
@form(action = routes.Application.submit(), 'enctype -> "multipart/form-data") {

    @inputText(
        uploadForm("name"),
        '_label -> "Name"
    )

    @inputFile(
        uploadForm("inputFile"),
        '_label -> "Queries"
    )
}
```

1. What is the best way to validate inputFile?
2. Is it possible do to that with annotations?

`@Required constraint` does not work at all.

I want it to be selected + add some limitation on size.

Answer (score 1):

make your form like:

```html
 <input type="file" name="inputFile">
```

In you submit method add this:

```java
 // from official documentation
    public static Result submit() {
      MultipartFormData body = request().body().asMultipartFormData();
      FilePart file = body.getFile("inputFile");
      if (inputFile != null) {
        String fileName = picture.getFilename();
        String contentType = picture.getContentType(); 
        File file = picture.getFile();
        // method the check size
        if(!validateFileSize){
          return redirect(routes.Application.index());    // error in file size 
        }
        return ok("File uploaded");
      } else {
        // here comes the validation
        flash("error", "Missing file");
        return redirect(routes.Application.index());    
      }
    }
```

Comment: Oh, sorry, i forgot to add:
is it somehow possible to do that with annotations?
Its a bit incosistent, that some validation comes from constraints in bean, and some validation comes from action.

Comment: I think @required wont work for files as the form object dosen't store the file It sends only textual data.

Comment: @AhmedAswani but if a field is File type. Shouldn`t required work ?

Comment: you are right, But the question does it binded or not I think file inputs are not binded, so It wont be validated

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following, maybe?

```java
MultipartFormData body = request().body().asMultipartFormData();
if (!body.getFiles().isEmpty()) { 
  // do your work
}
```